# java how to force refresh on url connection

Tags: java, url, page-refresh, urlconnection

I am behind proxy server and  I am using the following code to get data from url:

```
private static String getData(String address)throws Exception
    {
        System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies","true"); 
        Date d = new Date();
        String finalAdress = address+"?x="+d.getTime();
        URL url = new URL(finalAdress);
        System.out.println(finalAdress);
        InputStream html = null;

        HttpsURLConnection  con = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();

        con.setUseCaches(false);
        con.setDefaultUseCaches(false);
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.addRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

        //con.addRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
        con.addRequestProperty("Expires", "0");
        con.addRequestProperty("Pragma", "no-cache");
        html = con.getInputStream();



        //html = url.openStream();

        int c = 0;
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer("");

        while(c != -1) {
            c = html.read();

        buffer.append((char)c);
        }
        return buffer.toString();
    }
```

However when data changes on the server side - I sill for some time get the same old (cached) data as a response..

Tried to use:

-`Cache-Control`

-slightly modified urls `address+"?x="+d.getTime();`

but nothing seems to work.

Is there a way to force refresh as I would with a web browser (ctrl-F5) ?